# How to update a table name that is created from a variable within PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, variables, tablename

I am working on an automation project and the query I was given to automate has a variable in it called &Prev_MTH_YYYMM. The query joins to a table AB_&Prev_MTH_YYYMM. The actual table name is AB_202401. How can I change the join to reflect AB_202401 and then next month AB_202402 when the query needs to run again and so on for each month.  I only have access to the sql query and nothing that creates the new table each month as thats done within another process that the owner is unwilling to change.

I know this is not the optimal way to name a table but this is what I was given. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Ive tried to do this

select AA.1, AA.2, AA.3, B.1, B.2 from AA
JOIN  (select 'AB_'||(SELECT DISTINCT to_char(trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1))),'YYYYMM') from dual) from dual) B
ON AA.1 = B.1

and well this is not working.

Basically I need it to do this:

select AA.1, AA.2, AA.3, B.1, B.2 from AA
JOIN AB_202401 B
ON AA.1 = B.1

Comment: You cannot use a variable in place of a table identifier. If you want a dynamic table name then you need to build the query using string concatenation (make sure you take care not to generate a query vulnerable to SQL injection) and then run the query in PL/SQL using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or as a cursor. If you want to use the output from it in SQL then you could wrap it in a `PIPELINED` function.